# OpenShift Origin Build - unable to use git as a source

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm trying to do a simple build of a nodejs app I wrote in OpenShift Origin using the following yaml:

```
kind: "BuildConfig"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "dyn-kickstart"
spec:
  triggers:
    - type: "GitHub"
      github:
        secret: "secret101"
  source:
    git:
      uri: git@bitbucket.org:serverninja02/dynamic-kickstart.git
    sourceSecret:
      name: "github"
  strategy:
    type: Docker
    dockerStrategy:
      dockerfilePath: .
      forcePull: true
      noCache: true
  output:
      to:
        kind: "DockerImage"
        name: "docker-registry-default.apps.reedfamily.local/serverninja/dynamic-kickstart:v0.0.1
```

The command I'm running to create the build:

```
$ cat dynamic-kickstart.yml | oc create -f -
```

What I'm running into is that the build service account doesn't seem to be able to access the github url to clone:

```
Cloning "git@bitbucket.org:serverninja02/dynamic-kickstart.git" ...
error: build error: Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,192.168.1.81' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I did follow the instructions on creating the ssh-privatekey secret, placing in the secret store, and linking to the build sa. I also double-checked that key and tested through ssh forwarding that I can log into the OpenShift node and ssh git@bitbucket.org.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but even with using the http git url and making it a public repo, it still doesn't work as it complains about the peer certificate not being trusted:

```
Cloning "https://serverninja02@bitbucket.org/serverninja02/dynamic-kickstart.git" ...
error: build error: fatal: unable to access 'https://serverninja02@bitbucket.org/serverninja02/dynamic-kickstart.git/': Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
```

At this point, I'm unsure where to go with this as OpenShift Origin doesn't seem to want to build anything from git as a source.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

OpenShift Version: 1.3.0
OpenShift Kubernetes Version: v1.3.0+52492b4

This is a flat network behind a router. DNS is on Active Directory with a wildcard entry for *.apps.reedfamily.local.

This is a test bed environment in a .local domain. However I'm using this build to potentially build this out as a POC for my company to host OpenShift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem!!! So I'll share:

The /etc/resolv.conf was configured automatically during the build of my OpenShift nodes when I ran openshift-ansible. Unfortunately, there was a search domain placed in /etc/resolv.conf that must have been causing issues.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search apps.reedfamily.local
nameserver 192.168.1.40
```

Once I removed "search apps.reedfamily.local", that fixed the problem immediately on the next build!

Comment: The **/etc/resolv.conf** is normally handled by NetworkManager and on a openshift machine the openshift dispatcher scirpt add **# nameserver updated by /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-origin-dns.sh** to the last line. Was the ansible playbook successfully finished?